# How to control loading of controllers from other libraries in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have main project ( ASP.NET WEB API project ) and library project with controllers inherited from `ApiController` class.

When I start my application it load all controllers ( also from library ) and configure routes.
 For example: if in separated library I have `BooksController`, when I do request *api/books/get* it works. But I want to control when it works and when not, without removing or adding project references, just from code and dynamically.

Comment: An interesting read: http://beletsky.net/2011/12/inside-aspnet-mvc-instantiation-of.html

Comment: Are you saying you want to control when *controller routing* is set up ? Why do you want to this, just curious ?

Comment: i want to separated libraries with controllers and while developing start all in one asp.net project, just by adding references, but in production it will be separated in multiple asp.net projects. But I will need references to this libraries, because requests between those projects use same classes and I don't want to duplicate.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/